# Laravel 4 Update DB field to Null - Error

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

This code gives me an error:

```
$post = Post::find($post_id);
$post->deleted_at = null;
$post->save();
```

Here's the error:

```
Creating default object from empty value
```

Also tried

```
$post->deleted_at = '';
```

Which gave me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that you successfully found the database record you are looking for. The error comes from you trying to access a database column on a null object.

A simple check will avoid your error:

```
$post = Post::find($post_id);

if ($post !== null) {
    $post->some_date_field = null;
    $post->save();
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks. I was trying to return a record that had been soft deleted. This would solve it for me: `Post::withTrashed()->find($post_id);`

Answer (score 3):

If it does not find the model you'll have null in that variable, so you can:

```
$post = Post::findOrNew($post_id); /// If it doesn't find, it just creates a new model and return it

$post->deleted_at = null;

$post->save();
```

But if you really need it to exist:

```
$post = Post::findOrFail($post_id); /// it will raise an exception you can treat after

$post->deleted_at = null;

$post->save();
```

And, if it just doesn't matter:

```
if ($post = Post::find($post_id)) 
{
    $post->deleted_at = null;

    $post->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't aware of those two functions.